# 2 values in array, coding

Tags: php, arrays

Like you can do:

```
$array = array("stuff" => $stuff);
```

Cant you do:

```
$array = array();

$array[] = "stuff" => $stuff;
```

How can I do something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
$array = array( 'stuff' => $stuff );
```

or

```
$array            = array();
$array[ 'stuff' ] = $stuff;
```

Answer (score 4):

No, but you can do:

```
$array["stuff"] = $stuff;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the key inside the `[]`.

```
$array["stuff"] = $stuff;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  $array["stuff"]=$stuff should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array['stuff'] = $stuff;
```

is correct one